# Spellchecking restructured text in Sphinx and Python modules

Tags: python, sublimetext3, python-sphinx, spell-checking, restructuredtext

I am writing code documentation in restructured text in both Sphinx pages and inline in Python modules. What would be a good way to spell check the written  documentation so that

- Spellchecker would be aware of restructured text grammar and would skip e.g. links and not highlight them as spelling errors
- Spellchecker could be integrated with a text editor to run on background (Sublime Text)

Comment: why not use PyCharm instead, PyCharm checks spelling in docstrings like a... charm?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Sublime's spell checker](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/spell_checking.html) you can use a reStructuredText syntax highlighter, such as [RestructuredText Improved](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RestructuredText%20Improved).

The syntax highlighter will correctly identify most of reStructuredText's roles and directives.
Especially if you use your own roles and directives, there still might be some false positives (spelling errors that are actually correct reStructuredText syntax).

This means if you didn't develop python (or if you prefer a simple text editor for coding) don't need to use a full-fledged IDE.